# How to create a multilevel list from text in C# export to MS word

Tags: c#, devexpress

How to Create a Multilevel List from text in c# export to MS Word
Like the following Example:

1. Ibrahim was one of the ____ men.
   A) wise
   B) more wise
   C) wiser
   D) wisest

Comment: Hi, this consists of multiple steps. Creating he list from text and an export. Which part is your question about?

Comment: Yes, this is consist of multiple steps, like Multiple Choice Question Paper